# Why is this assumption needed in the Universational Introduction?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

($\forall$I). If $\gamma$ $\vdash$ [*t/v*], then $\gamma$ $\vdash$ $\forall$v$\phi$,

If t is

- either an individual constant not occurring in $\gamma$ OR
- an individual variable not free in $\gamma$.

May I know why are these two assumptions needed?